# Non exhaustive pattern matching for list with minimum 3 elements

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to solve the Heathrow-London problem [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functionally-solving-problems). The code compiles but when I call the function `heathrow` I get an error telling me I have `Non-exhaustive pattern matching`:

```
heathrow :: [Int] -> [Int]
heathrow [] = []
heathrow (x : y : z : zs)
    | x < y + z = heathrow (x : zs)
    | otherwise = heathrow (z : y : zs)
```

What am I doing wrong? It looks like every case is being covered.

Comment: It's not a non-exhaustive pattern matching "in guards". You have a pattern matching for empty list `[]` and another for lists with at least three elements, i.e. two cases uncovered.

Comment: Ah I see. how do i pattern match a list of only two elements?

Comment: `(x:y:[])` will do the trick

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `[x,y]` is arguably more readable.

Comment: `[x,y]` throws the same error

Answer (score 1):

This question can be answered by asking GHC: just enable warnings (the `-Wall` flag is enough).

```
Prelude> :load "ExhaustivePattern2.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling ExhaustivePattern2 ( ExhaustivePattern2.hs, interpreted )

ExhaustivePattern2.hs:6:1: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘heathrow’:
        Patterns not matched:
            [_]
            [_, _]
```

The last two lines show what shape of list we are not considering in our cases, namely the lists with exactly one or two elements.

Answer (score 0):

What about those cases?

```
heathrow [x]
heathrow [x, y]
```

Those aren't matched by neither `[]` nor `(x : y : z : xs)`. You have to match those too:

```
heathrow :: [Int] -> [Int]
heathrow []     = []
heathrow [_]    = []
heathrow [_, _] = []
heathrow (x : y : z : zs)
    | x < y + z = heathrow (x : zs)
    | otherwise = heathrow (z : y : zs)
```

Alternatively, you can either use guards:

```
heathrow xs | null (drop 2 xs) = []
heathrow (x : y : z : zs)
      ...
```

or move your matches:

```
heathrow :: [Int] -> [Int]
heathrow (x : y : z : zs)
    | x < y + z = heathrow (x : zs)
    | otherwise = heathrow (z : y : zs)
heathrow _ = []
```